# How to parse php inside html

Tags: html, wordpress

I tried to parse the php query into html, but on the html page **it shows array**.

My query looks like this: `$comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve') );`

I tried to print it on the html page using this: `$html .= $comments;`

Comment: You need to loop through each item in the array in a for loop, but keep in mind this isn't a WP question, it's a basic PHP question, stackoverflow would be a better place. I would recommend following a basic PHP course, it will quickly reveal a lot of these things to you that you really need to know, this is a gap in your knowledge of the fundamentals at the foundational layer of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/).

And as [Tom J Nowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57482/tom-j-nowell) commented, you need to loop through each comment and append the comment to the $html.

```
$args = array(
    'status'  => 'approve',
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
    $html .= $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content . '<br />';
endforeach;
```